# Pandas Dataframe: how to take the real part of an entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have created the following dataframe where every element is a complex number:
[image]

now I try to create a new dataframe df_real where every cell is the real part of the corresponding position in df_test. I tried np.real(df_test) but it doesn't work:

```
np.real(df_test)

Out[80]: 
array([[(279000.5663863553-0.0003399120878497263j),
        (145911.9152796151-6.691409775191625e-05j),
        (74302.47221500448-1.3390870745126033e-05j)],
       [(297275.8777515915-0.00038331836673437703j),
        (155312.8041194384-7.517068053101233e-05j),
        (55978.12197869339-7.562623734480566e-06j)],
       [(291927.6794481343-0.00035796935780514757j),
        (153590.01541398693-7.126840201788457e-05j),
        (76296.08360291217-1.3520006287818232e-05j)]], dtype=object)
```

I also tried

```
df_test.apply(lambda x: np.real(x))
```

but it doesn't work neither:

```
100000.000000  ...                                179396.984925
RAW_VAL_Element_Num                                               ...                                             
ELEMENT 0             (279000.5663863553-0.0003399120878497263j)  ...  (74302.47221500448-1.3390870745126033e-05j)
ELEMENT 2            (297275.8777515915-0.00038331836673437703j)  ...   (55978.12197869339-7.562623734480566e-06j)
ELEMENT 3            (291927.6794481343-0.00035796935780514757j)  ...  (76296.08360291217-1.3520006287818232e-05j)

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

finally I tried

```
df_test.apply(lambda x: x.real)
```

but since x is a column it doesn't have real as attribut.

**How can I take the real part of an entire dataframe?**

Comment: Hi, can you please add a short code so that we can create a similar `df_test`?

Comment: Are you certain your `df_test.dtypes` are complex numbers? `dtype=object` doesn't sound like it.

Comment: it looks like its tuples inside each column ... this will make everything slow and remove pretty much all the value  a dataframe brings ... you could try `df_test.values`

Comment: if df_test.dtypes are indeed object, how can I convert all df_test in complex numbers in one shot?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a tuple in every cell of your dataframe. To get the real part you have to apply a function to each numeric cell of your dataframe.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: np.real(x[0]))
```

This would get the first value in every tuple. To use this you have to select all the columns with tuples or set other ones as index

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. It seems to be the right strategy, however I made this work by saving my dataframe and reloading it. Now the reloaded dataframe has complex numbers as dtypes. I guess the credit's on you and also on some folks who commented on my post.

Comment: If you accept the answer I'll greatly appreciate it. At least you learned a way to apply any function to every cell in a dataframe. It is always helpful.